# Показать модальное окно через n переходов по внутренним ссылкам

Tags: jquery

Доброго дня,
подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать такое на jquery:
нужно сделать так чтобы после каждого 5 го перехода пользователя по внутренним ссылкам всплывало модальное окно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Записывать в куку пользователю кол-во переходов и когда оно кратно 5, то открывать модалочку. [для работы с куки](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

```
<head>
  <script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script>
    var i = $.cookie('step') || 0;
    i++;
    $.cookie('step', i);
    if(i%5 == 0) {
      //открытие модалки
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

Этот код должен быть на каждой странице сайта

Comment: Благодарю за исчерпывающий ответ

Answer (score 1):

Сделал как пример кликов по ссылкам, но ссылки должны открываться в новых окнах.

Если требуется сохранение при переходах на другие страницы, нужно использовать `localStorage`

```
window.globalClick = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('globalClick')) || 0;

$('a').on('click', function () {
  console.log('click', window.globalClick);
  if (window.globalClick == 5) {
    window.globalClick = 0;
    // код открытия модального окна
  }
  window.globalClick++;
  localStorage.setItem('globalClick', window.globalClick);
  return false;
})
```

**UPD**: добавил сохранение в `localStorage`

Comment: Благодарю за ответ